# Run Jenkins stage on different nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkinsfile of a multibranch pipeline architecture

```groovy
#!/usr/bin/groovy

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'ubuntu'
            customWorkspace "/src/$BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
    }
    environment {
        SRC_DIR = "$WORKSPACE"
        BUILD_DIR="/build/$BUILD_NUMBER"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                dir(BUILD_DIR) {
                    sh '$SRC_DIR/build.sh'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                dir(BUILD_DIR) {
                   sh '$SRC_DIR/test.sh'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to run the 'Build' stage on Ubuntu and Red Hat nodes in parallel, and the 'Test' stage on the Ubuntu node only.

Can anybody help me in specifying how to choose which stage are run on which nodes. I found few solutions online but they recommended rewriting the build stage twice: once for the Red Hat node and the other for the Ubuntu node. Isn't there a way to do this without code duplication ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 9):

Sure, you would want to label your slave nodes somehow. Basically configure all the node on Jenkins and give them meaningful names.

```
  stage('Build') {
   steps {
     node('os_linux') {
       sh './build.sh' 
     }
     node('os_redhat') {
       sh './build.sh' 
   }
  }
```

This will run the tasks in serial, and Jenkinsfile syntax also supports executing commands in parallel on different nodes.

Thanks,

Comment: But there is still the issue of code duplication i.e. "sh './build.sh' "

Comment: I agree, but node needs to have a step to execute right? so there will be some amount of duplication involved which is not unavoidable.

Comment: That's a shame though. I think it would be a good idea to be able to specify each stage should run on which agents

Comment: True. Please upvote the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: Seriously, just read the documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but still ...
You can use *script {}* so you can create the label you need.
Something like this:

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        script {
            dev label = 'RHEL'
            if (env.ENV == 'ubuntu') {
                label = 'Ubuntu'
            }
            node("${label}") {
                dir(BUILD_DIR) {
                    sh '$SRC_DIR/build.sh'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is asking to run "both" RedHat and Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree, my answer is not a complete solution. It is only a way to implement parameters to select different nodes. I guess that the code is a bit more than a simple build.sh or the code duplication would not be a concern at all. I would suggest using downstream pipeline like this and sending ENV parameter as shown above.