# Running a jenkins build on multiple CPU architectures

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for a way to use Jenkins to build a single code base for multiple CPU architectures.  at the moment this is amd_64 and armhf, although this may expand in the future.  The ideal situation would be to run the build over a number of different jenkins slaves with a different CPU architectures.

These build jobs are not compiler based (maven, gradle ext.) but system independ shell scripts (bash and python) which auto detect their CPU architecture and produce build artifacts to match the CPU.

I may be missing something really obvious, but I don't see a way to automatically run a build a number of times over different architectures or bind a specific build to a specific architecture.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can run stuff on different nodes in serial or even parallel execution. Check out [this small example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292060/3623345) in some related answer. Do you need any further assistance?

Answer (score 2):

Funny you ask this question now. Published last Friday (2019-11-22) ...

You should review the Jenkins blog:  [Welcome to the Matrix](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/)

> I often find myself needing to run the same actions on a bunch of
> different configurations. Up to now, that meant I had to make multiple
> copies of the same stages in my pipelines. When I needed to make
> changes, I had to make the same changes in multiple places throughout
> my pipeline. Maintaining even a small number of configuration was
> difficult for larger pipelines.

- [Single configuration pipeline](https://.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/#single-configuration-pipeline)
- [Pipeline for multiple platforms and browsers](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/#pipeline-for-multiple-platforms-and-browsers)
- [Excluding invalid combinations](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/#excluding-invalid-combinations)

Comment: While the answer is useful, the links at the end are unclear, and one is broken.

Comment: Fixed the one broken link; they were just pointers to the specific section sin the article. Almost 3 years since I answered; would have been nice if the OP provided feedback at the time (and upvoted/marked answered). I thought the post answered "Could anyone point me in the right direction" [to build a number of times over different architectures]